# Leer en la funcion main el return de las otras funciones secundarias

Tags: javascript

mi duda es simple intentaré explicarla de la mejor forma.
Quiero crear una funcion main, dentro de esa funcion main quiero crear varias funciones en las que introducire un código que devuelva true o false (a modo condiciones).

¿Cómo puedo leer desde la función main el valor booleano de las otras funciones?

EJ1:

```
function main (str){

// check if all the conditions return true
condition1(str);
condition4(str);
condition5(str);



function condition1 (str){
// code for condition
return true;

}
function condition2 (str){
// code for condition
return true;

}
function condition3 (str){
// code for condition
return true;

}
function condition4 (str){
// code for condition
return true;

}
function condition5 (str){
// code for condition
return true;

}
function condition6 (str){
// code for condition
return true;

}
function condition7 (str){
// code for condition
return true;

}

}
```

En este caso sería lo mismo (igual así me explico mejor) que hacer esto:

```
    // check if all the conditions return true
if(condition1(str)){
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
if(condition4(str)){
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
if(condition5(str)){
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: No entiendo cual es la duda pero almacenando el valor que retorna la función en una variable booleana después vas a poder hacer lo que quieras con esa variable.

Comment: Igual no me he explicado bien, te pongo un ejemplo:

`funcion condition1 devuelve true
funcion condition2 devuelve true
funcion condition3 devuelve false`

La funcion main debe comprobar que las 3 funciones son true para devolver true, si no devolverá false. ¿Como hago eso?

Comment: Por favor edita y limita el uso de etiquetas solo a aquella directamente relacionada con el lenguaje que estés usando

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues si he entendido bien la pregunta, creo que sería algo así:

```
function condicion1(str){

if(...){
return true;
}else{
return false;


}
}

function condicion2(str){

    if(...){
    return true;
    }else{
    return false;


    }
    }

function condicion3(str){

    if(...){
    return true;
    }else{
    return false;


    }
    }
```

Y dentro de la funcion main:

```
function main(str){

if(condicion1(str) && condicion2(str) && condicion3(str)){

   return true;
}else{
return false;

}

}
```

¿Es esto lo que buscabas? Un saludo

Comment: Por favor considera leer [answer], editar y agregar una explicación de tu código

Comment: Si gracias! Era algo simple pero no estaba muy seguro de como hacerlo,

Answer (score 1):

Si tienes 3 funciones que devuelven true o false simplemente compruebas asi:

```
//Creamos una funcion que toma 3 valores 
function check(func1 , func2 , func3){
    //comprobamos si los 3 valores son verdaderos
    if(func1 && func2 && func3){
        return true;
    }else{
        //retornamos falso en caso de que 1 o mas de los valores sea falso
        return false;
    }
}

var valor1 = true, valor2 = true, valor3 = true;
//para usar la funcion 
var checked = check(valor1 , valor2 , valor3);
console.log(checked);
```

Espero que te funcione esto